# How do I create a 3d scatter with a plane?

Tags: python, matrix, matplotlib, regression, scatter

I want to create a 3d plot that represents a multiple regression featuring two x variables. I want to have scatterplot points for the actual y-variable data and also a plane that represents the regression line generated by my two x variables. The extra complicating factor is that all of the variables are represented by matrices.

```
# Variables
a # 14x1 matrix representing an x variable
b # 14x1 matrix representing an x variable
c # 14x1 matrix representing the y variable
BETAS # 2x1 matrix holding the beta coefficients of the x variables
z = (BETAS[0]*a + BETAS[1]*b) # the expected value of c based on our regression
new_array # variable representing the regression line - used previously to plot the regression line in 2d space`

# Plot in 3d
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
plt.hold(True)
plt.plot(new_array[0], new_array[1], 'red')
ax.plot_surface(a, b, z)
plt.show()
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please take a look at how to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example of the code for your question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: e.g. instead of commenting what each variable holds, you could easily write code to set some random data: a = np.random.rand(14), etc. In that case any person answering your question can copy your code and help you solve the problem

Answer (score 3):

In order to find the regression parameters you can use the `normal equation`:

[image]

When dealing with **n** features you will get **n+1** regression parameters, so in your case you have **3** thetas. The plane can be represented using the plane equation:

```
p = theta0 + theta1*p1 +theta2*p2
```

In order to plot the plane, you need to create a mesh grid of points in your "feature" space. You can then use matrix multiplication to find the plane points.

[image: multiple regression plane separating points]

Here is the code:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

m = 14 #size of the matrix

#randomly generated data
x1 = np.random.uniform(0,10, (m, 1));
x2 = np.random.uniform(0,10, (m, 1));

y = np.random.uniform(0,1, (m, 1));

#combining of the features into a [m x 3] matrix
X = np.hstack((x1, x2))
X = np.hstack((np.ones((m, 1)), X ))

#calculating of the theta using the normal equation
theta = np.dot(np.dot( np.linalg.pinv(np.dot(X.transpose(), X)), X.transpose()), y)

#plane calculation
k = 10 #size of the plane

p1, p2 = np.mgrid[:k, :k]

P = np.hstack(( np.reshape(p1, (k*k, 1)), np.reshape(p2, (k*k, 1))))
P = np.hstack(( np.ones((k*k, 1)), P))

plane = np.reshape(np.dot(P, theta), (k, k));

#plotting
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

ax.plot(x1[:,0],x2[:,0],y[:,0],'ro') #scatter plot
ax.plot_surface(p1,p2,plane) #plane plot

ax.set_xlabel('x1 label')
ax.set_ylabel('x2 label')
ax.set_zlabel('y label')

plt.show()
```